# GOOGLE SHEET : VALUE parameter '+0.0050 ' cannot be parsed to number

Tags: regex, web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Any solution for this?

Error: VALUE parameter '+0.0050 ' cannot be parsed to number

Code : `=IFNA(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" & B3,"//*[@class=""D(ib) Mend(20px)""]/span[2]"), "^.*?\s")))`

I've try out with some other stocks, for those with a positive gain on the day, it shows the error, for those with negative loss, the is fine.

I think the problem is with the "+" sign.

[image: screenshot is here]

Comment: What is the value of B3? also what is the desired output you want>

Comment: Value of B3 is a stock code from yahoo finance, the value imported from yahoo finance is "+0.0050". The other values that I've import such as "-0.01", "-0.12" are working fine. You may refer to the screenshot.

Comment: I've try out with some other stocks, for those with a positive gain on the day, it shows the error, for those with negative loss, the is fine.

I think the problem is with the "+" sign.

Comment: I've tried, but it become blank. =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

```
=IFNA(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML(
 "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&B3, 
 "//*[@class=""D(ib) Mend(20px)""]/span[2]"), 
 "\+?(.*?\s)")))
```

[image]

Comment: Recently having issue with the code you gave, the cell became empty. Also previously the price data from yahoo finance shown an error : #NA (Resource at url not found.)

 I was using this code : 

=if(isblank(B3),"",ImportXML("https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/"&B3&"/history?p="&B3, "//tbody/tr[1]/td[6]"))

Comment: Any solution for this? Im very very new to coding, just at the beginning of learning to code.